# TFS 2010 Custom policy violation and escalation

Tags: tfs

This is for TFS 2010 checkins 
Is there a way to log or escalate in case a checkin happens overridding a custom checkin policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escalate? Not that I know of...

Log? TFS already does that.
http://vsts-fu.blogspot.com/2010/09/query-check-in-policy-overrides.html

Comment: e-mre thanks for the inputs. That helped me in starting off the blocks.

Comment: If someone needs to do the same using TFS API, here is the code VersionControlServer vcs = (VersionControlServer)Tfs.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));


            string path = "$/path";

            IEnumerable changesets = vcs.QueryHistory(path, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, "", null, VersionSpec.Latest, int.MaxValue, true, false);

          
            
            foreach (Changeset changeset in changesets)
            {

                
            }